# REST service returns bad gateway when file is big and processing takes too long

Tags: rest, iis, web-config, bad-gateway

I have made a REST service that receives a ZIP-file, process and check some stuff, and returns an ID. This works fine for smaller ZIP-files, but when sending larger files (currently testing with 17 Mb), and the processing takes longer, the service returns "502 Bad gateway - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server".

I have tried to change all the variables I could find in the web config:

```
    <binding name="webHttpTransportSecurity" maxReceivedMessageSize="163840000"     maxBufferSize="163840000" closeTimeout="04:00:00" openTimeout="04:00:00" receiveTimeout="04:00:00" sendTimeout="04:00:00">
        <security mode="Transport">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
        </security>
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"  maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>


    <requestFiltering>
           <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />


       <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" enable="true" requestLengthDiskThreshold="10240" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true" executionTimeout="1000" appRequestQueueLimit="4000000" />


    <serviceBehaviors>
           <behavior>
             <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
           </behavior>
         </serviceBehaviors>
```

Anyone have any idea how to make this work with bigger files? Where is this restriction, in IIS or something?

UPDATE: my code on server continue to run in the background and receives the whole file even though the caller of the service gets 'bad gateway'. So this is a 'false' 502.

Comment: Do you have a firewall installed?

Comment: Did you found any solution for this issue?